# How to edit an SVG image from the command line?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

Say I have an SVG map (see [example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World-v2-2011.svg)) of the world and I want to use the command line to paint a country with a different color.

If I was using a GUI, it would be enough to click on one point in the area of said country, and a bucket fill tool could do the rest, as each country is a separate and continuous region of color.

Is there any way to do this with ImageMagick or a similar command line tool, by giving a coordinate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open it in a text viewer and you will see that the example you posted is a really complex image.

the part of the file

```
<path id="path2384" fill="#BFBFBF"
```

You could change the color of the fill and if each part/country of the image was a separate path then you could color them by either referencing a external stylesheet like

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>
```

and using normal css targeting the ID's of the countries id="path2384"

Or you could run sed or a regex that modifies the fill and saves the file